# How can i load local video react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I am trying to load local video file to my react app. The video file exist in repo itself. I added the path of the video file as mentioned below but video is not loading.

```
export const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay loop muted>
        <source src="src/assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

    </>
  );
};
```

I am new to react world. Any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import the local video file to you component.

```
import myVideo from '../media/M_03292018202006_00000000U2940605_1_001-

class Video extends Component {
   render () {
     return (
      <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <ReactPlayer
          url={myVideo}
          ...
         />
      </div>
    )
   }
 }
```

Comment: It's video file. Can we import something is not exported?

Comment: Do you have any reference for the same?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to include the video from the files inside react app:

```
import videoFile from '../path-to-video.mp4';

export const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay loop muted>
        <source src="src/assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

    </>
  );
};
```

---

2. Another solution will be locate your video in `public` folder (within `index.html` and use the path like this (video is located in `public/assets/video/video.mp4`):

```
export const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay loop muted>
        <source src="/assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

    </>
  );
};
```

---

3. One more is to use absolute path:

```
export const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay loop muted>
        <source src="https://example.com/assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

    </>
  );
};
```